# How to say "along the way" when I mean it literally?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, translation

I wanted to help a foreigner looking for his guide. I said:

Go towards the church, you will meet your guide along the way.

I meant that he would meet him while going towards the church. What should I say instead of along the way which I think is idiomatic?

Comment: And how would the idiomatic meaning interfere with the literal one, at all? They are all but identical.

Comment: Wouldn't *on your way* be more natural and literal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the nearest synonym for either "along" or "way". This will keep you away from the set phrase "along the way".

For instance, use "You will meet your guide along the *road/path*", or "You will meet your guide *somewhere on* the way".

Answer (score 3):

I think it would make more sense to say *On the way there*

So: *Go towards the church, you will meet him on the way there*.